# SQL Server Union All with one different column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am using union all function inside two tables. Two tables are exactly the same except one column.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT x.InventoryTransTempID
    ,x.InventoryTransID
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM InventoryTransTemp

    UNION ALL

    SELECT *
    FROM InventoryTrans
    ) x
```

The only column which is different is the Identity column. In first table is called InventoryTransTempID and in Second InventoryTransID. Is there any way to inform sql server that if column name is InventoryTrans just renamed it to InventoryTransTempID.

My exception is:

> Invalid column name 'InventoryTransID'.

Comment: Short answer: `SELECT *` is antipattern use explicit names and alias them accordingly.

Comment: You could use a CTEs to get around this

Comment: Thank you JGFMK, could you please give me a short example?

Comment: Why are you selecting 2 columns? The result of UNION ALL is 1 column with the name that it has in the 1st query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error happens because when you perform union operation between two columns and try to get output in one column the name of column is the name of upper one column name as shown below.

```
Select 'a' as column1
union all
Select 'b' as column2
```

The output will be here

```
column1
-------
a
b
```

Here as per the above statement `column2` is mixed with `column1`, So you can not get both the column name in outer query.

To check the column name you should first check the output of the inner query which is as below.

```
select * from InventoryTransTemp union all select * from InventoryTrans
```

Comment: Thank you but i think in this case, i need to use two where statements, am i right? One for each select. That's what i was try to avoid

Comment: @ΔημήτρηςΧριστοφορίδης Yes, there is no meaning of combining two auto columns into one because here the values will be different only the data type will be same. Consider an example combining the StudentId and ExamId into one column is wrong but it will not give the error.

Answer (score 0):

The result of `UNION ALL` is all rows from both tables and the names of the columns are taken from the 1st query of the unioned queries.
So you can't have in the results both column names.
In this query:

```
select * from InventoryTransTemp
union all 
select * from InventoryTrans
```

the column's name will be `InventoryTransTempID`, 
and in this query:

```
select * from InventoryTrans
union all 
select * from InventoryTransTemp
```

the column's name will be `InventoryTrans`. 
You can change the name if you alias it in the 1st query.